# Retrieving field formats of numpy record array as list

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

I am trying regularize the formats of a pytable and recarray for the purposes of appending the recarray to the pytable.  To do this I need to get field information from the recarray (i.e. names and field formats)  I can easily get a list of the recarray names using:

```
namelist = Myrecarray.dtype.names
```

but have not found a corresponding property.  The recarray dtypes property returns a tuple list of name and format but it is not possible to iterate over this list to retrieve the formats.  This seems non-standard as I am able to iterate over other lists of tuples to obtain specific tuple items.  For example, the following code shows iteration over an array and recarray, and attempts to iterate over the list of tuples of the dtype of a recarray:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
print([x[0] for x in my_list])
print('-----------------------')

my_array =  np.array([(1.0, 2, 5), (3.0, 4, 77)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', int), ('z', float)])
print([x[2] for x in my_array])
print('-----------------------')

img = np.array([[(0,0,0), (1,0,0)], [(0,1,0), (0,0,1)]], {'names': ('r','g','b'), 'formats': ('f4', 'i2', 'f4')})
nta = np.array(img.dtype)
print(img.dtype)
print(img.dtype.names)
print(img.dtype[0])
print(nta)
print([x[0] for x in nta])
print([x[0] for x in img.dtype])
```

The printouts from this code (shown below) suggest that I can: 
1) iterate over a list of tuples;
2) iterate over a recarray; 
3) retrieve the dtype of a record array as an apparent list of tuples;
4) retrieve the names from the recarray
5) retrieve the format of one field of the recarray

but that I can not:

6) iterate over the recarray dtype to retrieve the format of each field
7) iterate over the recarray dtype cast as an array to retrieve the format of each field

the output is:

```
[1, 3, 5]
-----------------------
[5.0, 77.0]
-----------------------
[('r', '<f4'), ('g', '<i2'), ('b', '<f4')]
('r', 'g', 'b')
float32
[('r', '<f4'), ('g', '<i2'), ('b', '<f4')]
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\Python\test0.py", line 23, in <module>
    print([x[0] for x in nta])
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Does anyone know how to retrieve the field formats from a record array as a list?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm, newbie found an answer to his own question. I needed the "descr" property to turn it into an iterable object

```
print([x[1] for x in img.dtype.descr])
```